# Runtime-editable resource file

Tags: .net, asp.net

I've created a custom XML based Error Message framework for .NET. The XML is key-value based and this gets cached. The cache is invalidated when the user edits the XML file. When an error occurs, a call like 'GetError(Password.Toolong,"Default value")' happens which reads the cache.

What I want to know is whether a similar framework exists (maybe part of PnP) before I spend time making this thing a portable module.

I want to externalize my strings so I can edit them on the fly. I've read up on resx and settings files which don't seem to be easily editable during run time.

Answer (score 0):

XML will probably handle a single language just fine, for more languages, I would suggest moving to a database.